# Can I enlarge html datepicker?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to enlarge standart html date picker?
`<input type="date" name="date-picker">`
By default it's nearly 140x20 (my screen's resolution 1366x768, Google Chrome browser)
**UPD**: Thanks, TylerH.
I just forgot to change font-size, setting 'width'/'height' properties without font-size disfigured the datepicker.

Comment: Have you tried to make it bigger yourself? You can expand the width by just changing the width property in CSS.

Comment: @Grofight, welcome to Stackoverflow! To increase your chances of getting help, try improving your post by providing us with some more details. What did you try to make the datepicker larger? What's not working? etc. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the way, `<input type="date">` is currently not cross-browser compatible. Using the datepicker widget in JQuery UI might be a better idea for now.